# Cocoa macro-- unique question

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ipad, macros

I need help with a #define to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 47; ++i)  {     SETLABEL(i)     }
```

the SETLABEL() macro should take the intValue of "i" and paste it into a label name:

when i == 1-->    label1.text = (stuff)

when i == 2-->    label2.text = (stuff)

Is this possible? The following fails miserably, because it pastes "i" in, rather than the *value* of "i":

```
#define SETLABEL(x)    [label##x setText: [foo stringValue]];
```

EDIT:  Thanks for all the help. My code looks like this now:

the declaration for the int is iB[25]

```
-(void)stuff {
int x;
int labelGo = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < 25; ++i) {
    NSString * labelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"magicItemBoughtTot%d", i];
    UILabel * currentLabel = [self valueForKey:labelName];
    if (iB[i] == itemPH) { // if label is not empty
        [currentLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 
                                        ([currentLabel.text intValue] + 1)]];
        labelGo = 0;
    }
}
utilityNum = nil;
utilityNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:labelGo];
```

}

Comment: Why do you have 47 labels on a single screen?!

Comment: I actually have more like 250.  I could send you a screen shot, and you would understand why-- but I'd need a non-disclosure agreement ;)

Comment: Yeah, I tried a bunch of different ways, and always an outcome other than I'd hoped.  I only recently discovered macros, though, having been coding for only a few months.  The satisfaction of turning a few hundred lines of code into a *few* lines of code is a beautiful rush.

Comment: I'd definitely be interested in seeing your UI that requires 250 `UILabels`, because I'd be willing to bet money there's a better way to do what you're attempting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "real" answer to this question is to declare your labels with `@property` (which they probably already are), and then do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 47; ++i) {
  NSString * labelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d", i];
  UILabel * currentLabel = [self valueForKey:labelName];
  [currentLabel setText:(stuff)];
}
```

However, the real *question* here is: Why on earth do you have 47 labels that are all showing the same thing, and why on earth don't they have better names?

**edit** retrieving primitives:

While it's possible to retrieve the values of primitive ivars using stuff like `valueForKey:` or `object_getInstanceVariable()`, the fact that you're requesting this is (in my book) a sign of poorly designed code.  Even without looking at your code, I guarantee you that there's a better way to be doing this.

That being said, here's a loaded gun on how to get primitive values out of instance variables by name:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

//self has an ivar named "i"
int *iPtr = 0;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "i", (void**)&iPtr);
NSLog(@"%d", (int)iPtr);
```

However, if you ever use this code in a production environment for anything beyond explicitly debugging something, then I'd say you deserve any crashes you get.  (Not that this code is crash-prone, but rather that it'd be probably be representative of the rest of the code)

Comment: You are awesome (though you forgot the ", i" at the end of the stringWithFormat:).  The app is data-intensive-- and the labels do, actually, have more interesting names.  I was simplifying for the sake of clarity.

Comment: With your task is it also possible to use a tableview? I think that would be much more efficient. ;-)

Comment: Can you do something like this for ints, too?     And no, not possible to use a tableview.

Comment: @AMayes edited answer, but **YOU SHOULD NOT DO THAT**.  These questions indicate that your code is ripe for re-architecting.

Comment: @Dave I tried out something I've been curious about for a while: int newInt[25], then I cycle through with a for(;;) and alter the values that way.  So happy I figured that out, b/c I've barely seen it referenced at all, just figured I'd see if it worked, and viola!

Comment: @AMayes that's much better having 25 individual `int` ivars (though it still lacks the whole "this instance variable should have a descriptive name" element) :)

Comment: @Dave can you use the same device when naming IBOutlets?  e.g. UILabel genericLabel[25]?

Comment: @AMayes search the docs for `IBOutletCollection`. I've never used it personally, but I gather that it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `NSArray`, `NSSet`, and `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:`

Comment: So that would be a "no," then?

Comment: @AMayes: That would be a "using a proper collection is the right way to do it." What does having 47 numbered variables get you that an array does not, besides a lot of unnecessary code and a fragile design?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to set undeclared UILabels in an array for display.  I thought you were suggesting loading the array with the predefined pointers, which is tantamount to setting the labels individually in code, since I only have to change their values once.

Comment: That is a beautiful little device.  Thanks so much for calling my attention to it!